# Printing 'Left' or 'Right' based on random int with a lambda expression?

Tags: python, lambda

I read a (somewhat) humorous story about the TSA paying a developer $1.4M for an app that simply outputs a random "Left" or "Right" arrow.  I decided to try it myself in Python.

I am wondering if I could shorten the if-else statement using something like a Lambda expression or list comprehension... a syntactic shorthand for conditionally printing strings.

```
import os, datetime, random
while True:
    os.system('clear')
    print "ENTER to continue, or type 'quit'"
    print datetime.datetime.now()
    print ''
    i = random.randint(1,2)
    if i == 1:
        print 'Left'
    else:
        print 'Right'
    print ''
    prompt = raw_input("")
    if prompt == 'quit':
        quit()
```

Comment: what about [python ternary operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/394809/3651800) `print 'Left' if i==1 else print 'Right`. Note that although the requirements sound laughably trivial, depending on the requirements for the true randomness of the distribution it can be more difficult than one might naively think.

Comment: @MattCoubrough that is exactly what I had in mind.  I knew I had seen it before. thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a better random function:

```
import random
print(random.choice(('Left', 'Right')))
```

You could also use this trick:

```
('Left', 'Right')[random.randint(0, 1)]
```

Which will randomly index into the tuple. Go with `choice` though.

Check out the docs for [random](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html).

Also, the allowance for the TSA app was $360k. See [this hackernews comment](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11418118) for a cool breakdown of potential costs.

Comment: What makes you say the distribution isn't uniform? That's exactly what I would have expected it to be, so if there's something that suggests otherwise I'd be very interested.

Comment: @TomDalton I'll remove that part because I don't know for certain that it's not. The docs don't actually say for the choice function.

Comment: Minor note: Use a `tuple` literal, not a `list` literal, if you're doing this a lot. The `tuple` would be constructed at load time and reused; the `list` would be constructed at run time every time you make this call, which just adds unnecessary overhead.